# Modify the SQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, php-5.3

I want to count the **total row** where **parent id** is equal to **page id** in a `page table`,

```
SELECT 
    parent_id
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM page AS p
WHERE p.parent_id = p.page_id
AND p.type = 'page'
```

and I get this correct result,

```
parent_id   total
 1          16
```

but what if I want to change the **value** in **parent id** to `self`?

So I will get this as my final result,

```
parent_id   total
 self       16
```

is it possible?

Comment: if self represents parent_id itself... then just remove it from where condition...

Comment: What result were you expecting ? can you show some sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    'self' as parent_id
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM page AS p
WHERE p.parent_id = p.page_id
AND p.type = 'page'
```